# How to do a data frame join with pandas?

Tags: join, dataframe, pandas, jupyter-notebook

Can somebody explain data frame joins with `pandas` to me based on this example?

The first dataframe, let's call it `A`, looks like this:

[image]

The second dataframe, `B`, looks like this:

[image]

I want to create a plot now in which I compare the values for column `running` in `A` with those in `B` but only if the string in column `graph` is the same. (In this example, the first row in `A` and `B` have the same `graph` so I want to compare their `running` value.)

I believe this is what [`Pandas.DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) is for, but I cannot formulate the code needed to join the data frames `A` and `B` correctly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think I would use `merge` here:

```
>>> a = pd.DataFrame({"graph": ["as-22july06", "belgium", "cage15"], "running": [2, 879, 4292], "mod": [0.28, 0.94, 0.66], "eps": [220, 176, 1096]})
>>> b = pd.DataFrame({"graph": ["as-22july06", "astro-ph", "cage15"], "running": [395.186, 714.542, 999], "mod": [0.67, 0.74, 0.999]})
>>> a
    eps        graph   mod  running
0   220  as-22july06  0.28        2
1   176      belgium  0.94      879
2  1096       cage15  0.66     4292
>>> b
         graph    mod  running
0  as-22july06  0.670  395.186
1     astro-ph  0.740  714.542
2       cage15  0.999  999.000
>>> a.merge(b, on="graph")
    eps        graph  mod_x  running_x  mod_y  running_y
0   220  as-22july06   0.28          2  0.670    395.186
1  1096       cage15   0.66       4292  0.999    999.000
```